# OpenGL: Performing TexCoord calculations within shader, bad practice?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I’m currently working on a 2D graphics engine for a game. My shader takes in 2 UV offset floats and calculates the TexCoord by applying the offset.

Here is a sample of my vertex shader:

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 v_TexCoord;

uniform float u_Offset;
uniform float v_Offset;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    v_TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x + u_Offset, texCoord.y + v_Offset);
};
```

Should I worry about this causing performance issues in the long run? How big of a difference would it make if I were to perform the calculations CPU side before passing the final UV in, and is it worth optimizing?

Comment: How often does the offset change? In case it potentially changes every frame, doing the calculation on CPU side might even be slower than in the shader. Note, that calculating the final tex-coord on the CPU also means copying the whole geometry data back to GPU memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the attributes data of a mesh is the main purpose of programmable pipeline, moving it to the CPU will be translated into a peformance downgrade. Also, as pointed out by @BDL , you will need to re-send the data to the GPU, which is the worst part of the whole process.

A different case is when you are performing a calculation which is the same for all the shader instances, which will be more appropiate to perform such operation on the CPU and upload it as an uniform.

Comment: I would expect only a small handful of meshes in my engine to constantly have their coords updated (eg. scrolling backgrounds). Another case would be when animating an image with a spritesheet. In that scenario, I expect the coords to be updated once every couple of frames. But apart from those, images such as floors and walls would be tiled and remain unchanged throughout. Should I consider using multiple shaders to handle each unique mesh type and behavior?

Comment: If, aside from the texture coordinate modification, the rest of the shaders is the same (vertex shader, fragment shader, etc.), I would suggest to use an uniform variable (like a float) to control when that displacement is applied, so when you dont want to apply any, you set the uniform to 0.0 (...texCoord.x + u_Offset * controlFlag...). This would allow you to use a single shader, which means not changing program throught the rendering process. However, you can still choose multiple shaders, you wont notice a difference (modern game switch couple hundred to thousand times programs per frame)